# Angular: Are there some ways to re-compile dom?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Like the DOM, the directive 'cur' will change the DOM using `jQuery`, but not save in scope.
If I want to reflesh the DOM, I can compile and replace the DOM. The code is this : `$('#main').html($compile($('#main').html())($scope))`
But, there are better ways to directly compile DOM ?

```
 <div id="main">
    <div class="fl item" ng-class="cur == 1? 'cur':''" cur>111</div>
    <div class="fl item" ng-class="cur == 2? 'cur':''" cur>222</div>
    <div class="fl item" ng-class="cur == 3? 'cur':''" cur>333</div>
    <div class="fl item" ng-class="cur == 4? 'cur':''" cur>444</div>
    <textarea name="" id="msg" cols="30" rows="10" ng-bind="msg">
    </textarea>
 </div>
 app.directive('cur', function(){
    return function(scope,ele){
        ele.click(function(){
            ele.addClass('cur').siblings().removeClass('cur');
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Why you want to recompile if the only change you are doing is adding and removing class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use compile function in your directive:

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }
```

[see the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)